# Flipping a coin and getting heads 15/20 times

Tags: probability

If you flipped a coin 20 times, hoping to get a head each time but got a tails 5 times out of that 20, would the probability be roughly 1 in 2^20 divided by 50?

Comment: $\binom{20}{15}2^{-20}$

Answer (score 1):

The [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) provides you with the means to calculate this, since this is just the result of $n$ [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial):

$\mathbb P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Where $k$ is the number of successes (or heads in your case), $n$ is the total number of trials (coin tosses) and $p$ is the probability of getting head from a single coin toss.

If you believe the coin to be unbiased, then $p = 1 - p = \frac{1}{2}$ and thus

$\mathbb P(X = 15) = \binom{20}{15}\frac{1}{2}^{15}\frac{1}{2}^{5}$